# Non-italic custom command in theorem environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-fonts

I usually use `\text{}` in macro for names of functions such as `deg` that should appear in math environment in non-italic. It works fine as long as the macro is not used in a theorem environment, see the picture.

How can I avoid it, e.g. how to write the command so it works like the predefined `deg` (similar with `max` etc.).

[image: Example of the problem]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mydeg}{\text{deg}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    
    This is how \emph{regular} degree looks like: $\deg(v) = 1$.
    
    This is how \emph{my} degree looks like: $\mydeg(v) = 1$.
    
    This is how \emph{regular} degree looks like in a theorem environment:
    
    \begin{theorem}
        It is true that $\deg(v) = 1$.
    \end{theorem}
    
    This is how \emph{my} degree looks like in a theorem environment:
    
    \begin{theorem}
        It is true that $\mydeg(v) = 1$.
    \end{theorem}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is exactly why you should not use `\text` for math identifiers it is for accessing the current text font,  use `\mathrm{deg}` or better `\DeclareMathOperator\deg{deg}`

Comment: Now, when I know that such a thing exists, I will. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is exactly why you should not use `\text` for math identifiers it is for accessing the current text font, use `\mathrm{deg}` or better `\DeclareMathOperator\deg{deg}`

Answer (score 3):

You usually want `\operatorname{deg}` or (as David Carlisle recommended) `\DeclareMathOperator`.  These will give you a log-like operator with `\mathop` spacing.  (All of these commands depend on `amsmath`.)

Using `\mathrm{deg}` will remove all spacing, as if you were taking the product of math constants d, e and g.

If you want text spacing, the command you want to clear all font settings is `\textnormal{deg}`.  Another alternative I often use is `\textup`, which I can use in tandem with `\bfseries\boldmath` to make the operator names, the text and the math symbols all bold.  Finally, you can put arbitrary text-mode commands in `\text`, such as `\text{\upshape\ulcshape deg}` to turn off both italics and small-caps when using `fontaxes` or `fontspec`, but leave the weight unchanged.  You can also use this to select a different font without using up a symbol font alphabet.